# How to parse json from php server array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I send data from post to php server and it send me json array:

**json array response** (the json file is not always the same)

```
{
"id":1,
"md5":"12345ABC",
"md5_img":
{
"img1":"00000BBB",
"img2":"77777XXX"
}
}
```

**My class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    private EditText value, etid, etmd5;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private static final String LOGTAG = "LogsAndroid";

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etid);
        etmd5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmd5);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (value.getText().toString().length() < 1)
        {

            // out of range
            Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>
    {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground (String... params)
        {
            String datos=value.getText().toString();
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx/xxxxxxx");

            try
            {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Datos", datos));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


                Log.i(LOGTAG, responseBody);


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (Double result)
        {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate (Integer... progress)
        {
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        //to use https server
        public HttpClient getNewHttpClient ()
        {
            try
            {
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

                return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new DefaultHttpClient();
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

I want show each value on his Edittext I dont know how to do that I read about [JSONReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) but I can't show data on my app

Comment: Do you mean by "md5_img": 
"md5_img":""

Comment: @SmitaNarayan It's a array inside json array

Comment: Sorry my bad, that is fine.

Comment: The JSON seems correct: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a7d3079f296a3b84a47e2d7146b2b511

Comment: Thanks for that web, I don't known before @dthacker any suggestions to parse json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to parse the result using [GSon](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples)

for this, you will need to create an object like :

```
public class MyObject{  
  public int id;
  public String md5;
  public MyImagesObject md5_img;
}
```

and

```
public class MyImagesObject{  
  public String img1;
  public String img2;
}
```

and then:

```
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyImagesObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject. Example:

```
String response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
int id = json.optInt("id", 0);
JSONObject jsonInner = json.optJSONObject("md5_img", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would parse the `String` response body into a `JSONObject`:

```
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            long id = object.getLong("id");
            String md5 = object.getString("md5");

            JSONObject md5_img = object.getJSONObject("md5_img");
            String image1 = object.getString("img1");
            String image2 = object.getString("img2");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

From there you can decide if you want to create a model class to parse these values into so you can save it into a database or just access it from memory as needed.

Comment: I like but the json file is not always the same, something more general? using for each for example?

Comment: If you post to a URL you should always expect the same JSON structure in its response. 

Why would you want your JSON structure to be different each time?

Comment: is not always the same json because I need send data to server then depending the data I send I receive diferent json each time

Comment: That seems like a bad design for your server responses, it will be very difficult to detect what JSON parsing method you need to use. 

You might want to consider having multiple endpoint urls to post different sets of data to and then have a delegated parsing method for each url. That way you can always rely on the JSON structure being stable.

Comment: Can you post the different formats that the JSON response might come back as?

Comment: Impossible, I never know format that I going to receive next time...that's the problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72783/discussion-between-dthacker-and-aspicas).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json only when you know what data is in the json response.
There is two way you have following oprions-

1. Either parse it element by element using the proper keys for the values. like-

   ```
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
       String md5 = jsonObject.getString("md51");
       JSONObject innerJSONObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject("md5_img");
   ```

OR 2. Use some libraries like GSON or JACKSON for the parsing directly to the class objects as Mathieu de Brito has suggested above.